# How to store the root of my "subsite"

Tags: php, relative-path, document-root

I need to add my "web app" to an existing site. It will be placed in a separate folder.

What is the best way to define the root for my app? It will have no interaction with the rest of the site.

I thought of just creating a `.php` script in my root and do something like:

```
define('ROOT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__));
```

And then include this file in all other scripts.

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: What did not work for you? Others can not say you what is *right* for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FROM PHP DOC](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) on `dirname(__FILE__)` or `__DIR__`

> Given a string containing the path of a file or directory, this function will return the parent directory's path.

This can easily change depending on our be structure and one single config file

eg.

```
http://example.com = /public_html
http://example.com/mobile = /public_html/mobile
```

My Advice .. HARD CODE it since it is always fixed

```
define('ROOT_DIR','/public_html');
```

if you have a file in `/public_html/class/HelloWord.class.php`

You can easy access it has the following no matter your current directory

```
 ROOT_DIR . '/class/HelloWord.class.php' ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your method is also correct but it is matter of personal choice. I prefer using absolute URL over relatives as I **personally feel** absolute URL are less error prone.

For any web application that we make in core PHP (without using any framework), we define a config.php file with two following entries (Obviously with other too)

```
$WEBPATH="http://www.example.com/";
$OSPATH="/home/user/public_html/";
```

First two lines on any other php file are:

```
if(!defined(ANY_VAR_SET_BY_VALID_FILES)) die 'Invalid file';
require_once('path/config.php');
```

After that, all the paths/URL use $WEBPATH or $OSPATH.