# How to find the relative path to a php file that is included in another php file?

Tags: php

First of all I would like apology if this question has already been answered, I'm searching for two days with no luck.

Here is my setup:

I have 2 php files, in 2 different folders:

AAA/1.php
AAA/BBB/CCC/2.php

"2.php" is included in "1.php".

Since I need to use "2.php" in several different folders, I need it to be able to know in what folder he's localized. So in "2.php" I should have some code like:

```
    $directory = [whatever code I need to know where I am];
```

So in the above example, the relative path should be: BBB/CCC

I tried with several functions and coding I found but I can only get the full server path to "1.php".

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886788/how-to-store-the-root-of-my-subsite/12886827#12886827

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is `dirname(__FILE__);`

See [PHP: Magic Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) and [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) for more info.

> `__FILE__`    The full path and filename of the file. If used inside an include, the name of the included file is returned. Since PHP 4.0.2,
>   **FILE** always contains an absolute path with symlinks resolved whereas in older versions it contained relative path under some
>   circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

You could use document root as start of your path so you never have to worry about it.

e.g.

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/AAA/1.php'
```

and

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/AAA/BBB/CCC/2.php'
```

should work from no matter where you are as long as your php.ini configuration doesn't change too much.

Or you could use combinations of [basename()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php), [dirname()](http://php.net/dirname)