# finding a file in php that is 4 directories up

Tags: php, include, directory, root

I cannot locate the file even when using multiple `../` to find the file:

```
root -> public -> secure -> lock  -> login / "data.php"
                            panel -> data -> list / "list.php"
```

I want to include `data.php` with my `list.php` and tried doing the following to include the data:

```
include("../../../../lock/login/data.php");
include("../../../lock/login/data.php");
and also
include("../../lock/login/data.php");
```

However, this doesn't seem to work, but if I place it beside `list.php` and do the following, it reads the data just fine:

```
include("data.php");
```

What am I doing wrong with my code and what is a better way to execute this?

Comment: I think you should look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12886788/how-to-store-the-root-of-my-subsite/12886827#12886827 ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Learn to use**:

```
__FILE__; // for your current file path
dirname(__FILE__) or __DIR__; // for your current file parent folder
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']; // for your sites inception folder, your pivotal point
```

This should get you on your way. **Then you can**:

```
include __DIR__.'/../file-REALLY-relative-to-directory-of-edit-file.php';
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/absolute-path-reliable-for-your-site.php';
```

**NEVER EVER DO RELATIVE INCLUDES LIKE** *(current directory can change and break your world)*:

```
include 'an-unreliable-NOT-REALLY-relative-file.php';
```

*Hope it helps!*

Comment: DARN GOOD EXPLANATION ! XD don't break my world!

Answer (score 1):

Use phps `include_path` feature instead and specify those directories that contain php scripts to be included. Easier and safer.

Comment: how do i contruct an include path from that?

Comment: Google delivers hundreds of good hits if you simply enter "php include path".