# include, require and relative paths

Tags: php, relative-path, require-once

I'm not sure why I always have some many problems with this. Anyways this is the path to the file I want to require

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/htdocs/Classes/DBConnection.php
```

This is the path to the file that has the require statement

```
/var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/htdocs/Classes/Forecast/MyFile.php
```

and this is the require statement in MyFile.php

```
require_once '../DBConnection.php';
```

I keep getting the "failed to open stream" error. It works fine if I put in an absolute path. Does anyone see the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/Classes/Forecast/MyFile.php` is included from `/index.php` the relative path will be from the index file. To solve this, use [`__DIR__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php). The require will then be relative from that file.

`require_once __DIR__.'/../DBConnection.php';`

Comment: Yes this works! I'm a little confused though. I was under the impression that the ../ would move me back one dir from where I was.

Comment: I should add that it's not being included from index.

Comment: @Casey It's current directory dependent while __DIR__ is current file dependent. Current directory can change arbitrarily but current file directory... not really :)

Comment: @Casey The index file was just an example.

Comment: Maybe this is where I'm confused. The file I'm going to in my web browser is showing a list. So in that file is something like `$list=MyFile::getlist();foreach($list as $li){echo $li;)` So is calling a static function like that similar to a include in that MyFile path is now the same as the page that is calling?

Answer (score 1):

I have **a detailed answer** on this in another question:

[finding a file in php that is 4 directories up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999809/finding-a-file-in-php-that-is-4-directories-up/13000215#13000215)

It explains the caveats of relative file paths in PHP. Use the magic constants and server variables mentioned there to overcome relative path issues.

Answer (score 0):

Yep. The path is relative to the file your including your class file MyFe.php from and not the class file itself.   I am assuming MyFile.php is not really the page being served, but an included or autoloaded class.

Comment: No it is the file being served. I'm testing it now so I'm going to it directly instead of through index for example.

Answer (score 0):

Make your path relative to the initially requested file.  So if you're hitting /var/www/vhosts/mysite.com/htdocs/index.php, which includes MyFile.php, your path would be "Classes/DBConnection.php"

Comment: No it is the file being served. I'm testing it now so I'm going to it directly instead of through index for example