# PHP Relative paths for require file

Tags: php

I've been going over those two topics:

- [include, require and relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13104277/include-require-and-relative-paths)
- [PHP - with require_once/include/require, the path is relative to what?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1954750/php-with-require-once-include-require-the-path-is-relative-to-what)

and couldn't make my script to work, none of presented methods are working or maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Anyway this is where my problem occurred:

```
Root/                                   //this is root location for server
APP/                                    //this is root location for script
Root/APP/core/init.php                  //this is where I include classes and functions from
Root/APP/classes/some_class.php         //this is where all classes are
Root/APP/functions/some_function.php    //this is where all functions are
```

and so obviously I need to include `init.php` everywhere so I did in every file like this:

```
require_once 'core/init.php';
```

it was working until I have decided to create a location for admin files like this:

```
Root/APP/Admin/some_admin_file.php
```

and when I included init this way:

```
require_once '../core/init.php';
```

script failed to open functions, no such file in `APP/Core/` folder
so I used DIR method presented in topic above and than even weirder thing happened, error:

> no such file in APP/Core/classes/Admin/

What is that? :D I'm lost with this, could someone help a bit ;)

Comment: Check the letters case, are they in caps like this : APP/Core/ or APP/core/ , either one of them is wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include paths are relative to the current working directory, which can be inspected using `getcwd()`; this can be a source of many issues when your project becomes bigger.

To make include paths more stable, you should use the `__DIR__` and `__FILE__` magic constants; for instance, in your particular case:

```
require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/init.php';
```

The `dirname(__DIR__)` expression is effectively the parent directory of the script that's currently being run.

Btw, `__DIR__` could also be written as `dirname(__FILE__)`.

Comment: if i do this `require_once dirname(__DIR__) . '/core/init.php';` in admin file in admin folder i get this error: `Warning: require_once(functions/my_function.php) [function.require-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /APP/core/init.php` so its like trying to open function/function from core folder

Comment: @PatrickMevia Yes, well, that just means the problem must be fixed there too :)