# Is there any way to make all PHP paths in a site, root-relative?

Tags: php, path, root

Whenever I want to include a document with PHP, or perform any other PHP action which requires a path to be described, I need to write something like, `../../../../../document.html`. This works, but it's tedious, and in some cases, the path is wrong, resulting in code appearing on-page, and debugging.
This can, obviously, be bypassed by using the `$SERVER_['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` command, but that, too, requires a sometimes unmanageable amount of code (again, when many, many paths are present).
Is there any way to simply define all PHP paths site-wide to be document root-relative, as in HTML (`/document.html` is root relative)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [finding a file in php that is 4 directories up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999809/finding-a-file-in-php-that-is-4-directories-up)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to do that and have those problems.  Then I switched my site to use `mod_rewrite` for the urls.  I then had all of my php pages in the same directory so I didn't have to go a confusing 4 times up the directory structure to find the root.  You can have a php file on your server at:

```
/var/www/index.php
```

And, using mod_rewrite in your .htaccess file, you can have that map to:

```
http://domain.com/really/long/path/structure/page.html
```

When I moved over to that structure, it really helped me on the php side of things specifically regarding navigating to different directories.

Answer (score 1):

I have **a detailed answer** on this in another question:

[finding a file in php that is 4 directories up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999809/finding-a-file-in-php-that-is-4-directories-up/13000215#13000215)

It explains the caveats of relative file paths in PHP. Use the `magic constants and server variables` mentioned there to overcome relative path issues.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Most experienced developers would tend to define constants in a config file for various paths important to the application.  So perhaps something like this if you want to define the webserver document root as your application root, and perhaps have another path otuside the web server directory where you place application includes (classes, etc.) that you don;t want exposed in the web directory.

```
define('WEB_ROOT', $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
define('INCLUDE_DIR', '/path/to/directory/');
```

You can then just reference these constants in your application.

I would certainly recommend going away from relative paths as they are problematic when refactoring your code or moving your code from one server to another.  If you need relative type of paths (for app portability for example) you might be better served using the PHP magic constants like `__FILE__` and `__DIR__`.